# Web Login using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scripting, python-requests

I want to login to the given URL i have tried a solution but cannot verify that it is working. How can i make sure it logged in correctly. Any advice will be helpful. Thanks.
I am a beginner.

```
 import requests

#from lxml import html
login_url = 'https://epaper.thehindu.com'
req_url = 'https://epaper.thehindu.com/Home/Index'
payload = {
    "Email": "email",
    "Password":"pass"

}

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(login_url, data=payload)
    r = session.get(req_url)
    print (r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to examine if the requests Session cookies have changed. A login will usually add a cookie  to your session cookie jar which you might check programmatically.

```
import requests

target_url = 'url'
target_user = 'user'
target_pw = 'password'

payload = {
    'username': target_user,
    'password': target_pw
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    print(session.cookies)
    r = session.post(target_url, data=payload)
    print(session.cookies)
    session.close()
```

Comment: Result :<RequestsCookieJar[]>
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie ASP.NET_SessionId=rmuhkqj1pw4pqfijliveoyus for epaper.thehindu.com/>, <Cookie AWSALB=4G0tuJMSSDbqQP1CkwBqSGjQ7AtXoy8BOFJYuyQnSGgnQx21+wPaz+5SUHVMy5cCnCNHR4sj3HXqZy4jzMxd0Okr9+mdbd3JPxRYkyLcNZnd0czYsFOHLtDU/DO/ for epaper.thehindu.com/>, <Cookie __RequestVerificationToken=KhdHzfcPxV6ysAP18WAvUWkIN35_kB1nBSiCaDirq9jSzFtm6ghuyMvx6JGR4MCPFa3hvJx_uUti34w497Kro0tmPFjCg-OnYBlVhAe1qT41 for epaper.thehindu.com/>]>

Answer (score 0):

Try the below way. I suppose you get a valid response now. There is still some confusions about the payload parameters cause I can't check it in the right way as I don't have access to that page. Make sure to input `email` and `password` within the payload fields. Give it a shot:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://epaper.thehindu.com/'
req_url = 'https://epaper.thehindu.com/Login/ValidateLogin'

with requests.Session() as session:
    res = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

    payload={
        '__RequestVerificationToken':soup.select_one("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']")['value'],
        'Email':'',  #your email
        'Password':'', #your password
        'hiddenTab':'' 
        }
    r = session.post(req_url,data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    print(soup.title)
```

Comment: It is printing the title of the page...
what about the hidden tab and why did you use a requestverificationtoken

Comment: Try using chrome dev tools to see how a post request is processed and which parameters need to be passed along with the request. The fields I have made use of within `payload` can be found if you press the right link populated under `xhr` tab within `network` section in chrome dev tools. Btw, if it works, make sure to accept it as a solution by ticking the `checkmark` next to my answer.